# Replacing all starting characters that isn't a letter in regex

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace

I need to replace all  *starting*  characters that isn't a letter, but my regex pattern is replacing  *all*  of them. How do I fix this?

```
$text = "!@#$%^text!@#$%^";
$text = preg_replace("~[^\w]~", "", $text);

echo $text;
```

**result:**

```
text
```

**need result:**

```
text!@#$%^
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem is that you are using `preg_replace` that replaces all matches inside the string, while you need to remove just a sequence of non-word characters at the beginning of the string only.

Use an anchor and a quantifier:

```
$text = preg_replace('~^[^\w]+~', "", $text);
```

Or use `\W` instead of `[^\w]` (since it matches the same set of characters) to shorten the regex a bit:

```
$text = preg_replace('~^\W+~', "", $text);
```

See [IDEONE demo](http://ideone.com/wmmf9h)

*Explanation:*

- `^` - start of string
- `[^\w]+` - 1 or more characters (`*`) other than a word (`[a-zA-Z0-9_]`) character.

To also match digits as well as non-word characters just create a *character class* `[\W\d]`:

```
'~^[\W\d]+~'
```

Here is a [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/qC6aC8/1)

A character class will match either `\W` (a non-word character) or `\d` (digit), 1 or more times (due to `+`).

Comment: Um, I forgot to mention this, but I also don't want it to start with numbers either, and I just remembered that \w also include numbers. What should I use instead, in this case?